# Get the JSONObject in the right order

Tags: java, json

I am using `org.json` library and  am trying to create JSON Object `stops` in the simple form as below but I am always getting all `timeEntries` in the same JSONArray `timeArray` and the name is always changes in the stops as  in the `current output`

**Current output:**

```
{"arrival_time":
                {"mon-fri":[
                               ["04:48","05:18","05:46","06:16"],
                               ["04:52","05:22","05:50","06:20"],
                               ["04:57","05:27","05:56","06:26"]
                           ]
                },
"stops_name":"third name"}
```

**Code:**

```
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONObject stops = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject arrivals = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray arrivalMoFr  = new JSONArray();

    for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String name = entry.getKey();
        List<String> timeEntries = entry.getValue();                        
        try {                       
        stops.put("stops_name", name);

        JSONArray timeArray = new JSONArray(timeEntries);
        arrivalMoFr.put( timeArray);

        arrivals.put("mon-fri", arrivalMoFr);

        stops.put("arrival_time", arrivals);

        System.out.println(stops.toString(3));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Simple how  should the result like**

```
{"arrival_time":
                {"mon-fri":["04:48","05:18","05:46","06:16"]

                }
"stops_name":"first name"},
{"arrival_time":
                {"mon-fri":["04:52","05:22","05:50","06:20"]

                }
"stops_name":"second name"},
{"arrival_time":
                {"mon-fri":["04:57","05:27", "05:56","06:26"]

                }
"stops_name":"third name"}
```

Comment: what was your input json?

Comment: A quick look suggests that you should move your `stops` and `arrivals` declaration and initialisation inside the for loop. That should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that you want an *array* as your root object. You'll have to create the other array and objects multiple times, so initializing them outside the `for` loop isn't useful.

```
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray stops = new JSONArray();

for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String name = entry.getKey();
    List<String> timeEntries = entry.getValue();                        
    try {
        JSONObject stop = new JSONObject();                     
        stop.put("stops_name", name);

        JSONArray timeArray = new JSONArray(timeEntries);
        //arrivalMoFr.put( timeArray);

        JSONObject arrivals = new JSONObject();
        arrivals.put("mon-fri", timeArray);

        stop.put("arrival_time", arrivals);
        stops.put(stop);

        //System.out.println(stops.toString(3));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why am I getting the brakets twise ` "arrival_time": {"mon-fri": [[` as well at the end of the JSONArray too?

Comment: You don't need the `arrivalMoFr` then - you can directly use the `timeArray` in `arrivals`. I'll update the answer later.

Comment: and in this `stops.add(stop);` line here  it calls put and not add?

Comment: Sorry - mixed up with another language. Should be `put` indeed.